# Remove an object from an array of if not Present in Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project in React. In this Project, I have some array of users stored and I have one more array that contains `message` objects having three properties `from`, `to`, and `message`. Now I want, if the user id is not present message array then remove the `user` from the list. I am using Node.js as a backend. Or in simple words if the user has not sent or received any messages, then remove from them from the user list. Or if there any other solution for storing the `users` and `messages` in a single array.

users.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Rampal"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Anisha"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "john"
  }
]
```

messages.json

```
[
  {
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "message": "Please call me"
  },
  {
    "from": 3,
    "to": 2,
    "message": "Please call me"
  }
]
```

Showusers.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ShowSingle from "./ShowSingle";
import ShowRecentSingle from "./ShowRecentSingle";

function Showusers() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3005/")
      .then(function (response) {
        setUsers(response.data);
        console.log("users" + JSON.stringify(response.data));
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {!loading &&
        users.map((user, id) => <ShowRecentSingle key={id} user={user} />)}
      <input
        type="text"
        name="message"
        id=""
        className="message-input"
        placeholder="type new message....."
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Showusers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution with Map

You can maintain a [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of active users who either send or receive messages and then filter out inactive users from the array of users with it.

```js
const usersArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Rampal"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Anisha"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "john"
  }
];

const messagesArrary = [
  {
    from: 1,
    to: 2,
    message: "Please call me"
  },
  {
    from: 3,
    to: 2,
    message: "Please call me"
  }
];

const getActiveUserProfiles = (messages) => {
  // map of users who sent or receive messages
  const activeUsers = new Map();

  messages.forEach(({ to, from }) => {
    activeUsers.set(to, to);
    activeUsers.set(from, from);
  });

  // filter out inactive users
  return usersArray.filter(({ id }) => activeUsers.get(id));
};

const activeUserProfiles = getActiveUserProfiles(messagesArrary);

console.log(activeUserProfiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let users = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Rampal"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Anisha"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "john"
    }
  ];

let messages = [
    {
      "from": 1,
      "to": 2,
      "message": "Please call me"
    },
    {
      "from": 3,
      "to": 2,
      "message": "Please call me"
    }
  ];


let res = users.map(x => Object.assign(x, messages.find(y => y.from == x.id)));

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    if(res[i].from === undefined) {
        res.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: User ID 2 must be present in the result as it sent and received message.

Comment: User ID 2 is receiving but not sending, right?

Comment: Right, it's just receiving. But either way, it must be present as OP has quoted *Or in simple words **if the user has not sent or received any messages**, then remove from them from the user list.*